# Need to get only the value from the output

Tags: shell, sqlplus

When I execute a DB query via shell script I get the following output

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Thu Jun 22 02:50:47 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> 
SUM(SUM(CURRENTCOUNT))
----------------------
           1182870

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
```

I need to use `sed` to remove the other contents in it and get only `1182870`
i used

```
sed -n '/COUNT(\*)/{n;n;p}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command with minor changes.

```
<sql-command>|sed -n '/CURRENTCOUNT/{n;n;p}'
           1182870
```

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the display of column headings in *sqlplus* report, enter:

`SET HEADING OFF`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699001

Answer (score 0):

`the-sql-command | grep -A 2 '^SUM(SUM' | tail -n 1 | grep -o '[0-9]*'`